# Azure Wide and Deep Recommender real inference pipeline error - Invalid graph: You have required input port(s) unconnected

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

It seems like there is bug in create real-time endpoints for "Wide & Deep Recommender" module at least with the sample workflow.  I kept getting "Invalid graph: You have requested input port(s) unconnected".  Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Repro Steps:

1. Go to Azure ML -> Designer -> "Wide & Deep based Recommendation - Restaurant"
   [image]
2. Train the model -> Create "Real-time inference pipeline" -> in Real-time inference pipeline, click "Submit" -> Error occurs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can now register a trained model in Designer into the model registry and use automatically generated score.py/conda yaml to deploy it using SDK or CLI. After successful model training, publishing to inference cluster in [authenticating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-designer-automobile-price-deploy) to the AKS cluster and [consume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/algorithm-module-reference/web-service-input-output).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I just deleted the 'Evaluate recommender' at the end (having a yellow exclamation mark) and submitted again.

That fixed my problem.